# C++ assignment operator during declaration

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

This is my class Hero with two overload assignment operators - Hero to Hero and String to Hero.

```
#include <iostream>

class Hero {
private:
    int         x;
    std::string name;
public:
    Hero():x(42), name("JohnDoe") {};
    Hero(int a, std::string b):x(a), name(b) {};

    
    void print(){
        std::cout<<name<<" : "<<x<<"\n";
    }

    const Hero &operator =(const Hero &other){
        std::cout<<"Overloaded Assignment class to class! \n";
        x    = other.x;
        name = other.name;
        return *this;
    }

    const Hero &operator =(const std::string N){
        std::cout<<"Overloaded Assignment from string! \n";
        x    = 777;
        name = N;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main(){

    Hero foo(42, "Hercules");
    Hero zak = foo; // Regular assignmnet, not the overloaded
    
    // Hero bar = "HelloWorld";  <<<<  Illegal
    Hero zoo(HelloWorld",42);  <<  Ok, but here we use constructor, not an assignment operator

    Hero bar; 
    bar =  "Ayax";  // "Overloaded Assignment from string! \n";
    
    zak = bar; //"Overloaded Assignment class to class! \n";
    zak.print();
    bar.print();
}
```

And the produced result:

```
Overloaded Assignment from string! 
Overloaded Assignment class to class! 
Ayax : 777
Ayax : 777
```

Why can't I use overloaded operators for variable initialization in declaration?

In the line `Hero zak = foo;` compiler uses non-overloaded operator and the string `Hero bar = "HelloWorld"` is just illegal.

Comment: Initialization always invokes constructor and never assignment operator, presence of `=` is misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When initializing an object at definition, it's not using assignment even when the `=` syntax is used.

When you do:

```
Hero zak = foo;
```

it's equivalent to:

```
Hero zak(foo);
```

Which is copy-initialization and as such invokes the copy-constructor.

---

The problem with

```
Hero bar = "HelloWorld";
```

is that it's equivalent to:

```
Hero bar = Hero("HelloWorld");
```

which in turn is equivalent to:

```
Hero bar(Hero("HelloWorld"));
```

And since you don't have a constructor for `Hero("HelloWorld")` it's invalid.