# Why didn't initialization call the assignment operator

Tags: c++, constructor

See the following codes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
struct X {
  X() {  std::cout << "X() " << std::endl; }
  X(const X &) {  std::cout << "X(const X &) " << std::endl; }
  X &operator=(const X &) { std::cout << "operator= "<< std::endl; return *this;}
};

X f5() {
  X x;
  return x;
}

int main() {
  //Case 1:
  cout << "case 1:"<<'\n';
  X x5 = f5();
  //Case 2:
  cout << "case 2:"<<'\n';
  X x1;
  X x2 = x1;
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
case 1:
X()
case 2:
X()
X(const X &)
```

If you view the output, you will find that case 2 called the copy constructor, but case 1 did not. So why? What causes the difference. It seems to me that both are doing the same thing that's initialization.

Comment: In `X x5 = f5();` the `=` describes the **initialization**. It is **not** an assignment operator. Initialization is done with a constructor.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When returning a temporary object that is immediately assigned to another object, the compiler is allowed to do an optimization called copy elision: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision.

That avoids the extra construction.

Comment: More specifically, the optimization in the question is called NRVO.

Comment: This information is correct, but does not answer the question. In the case where a variable is declared and immediately initialized using an `=` symbol, the assignment operator is _never_ used (and not even required to be present). It's called [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64693866/c-assignment-operator-during-declaration.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Why I didn't find these concepts in the book c++ primer which should be a very comprehensive book, right?